# shell clean up script advice

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can you let me know your thoughts on this script and if you think it can be improved by any method?

I'm trying to create a clean up script that will run once a week by a cron job by root on our linux servers.

At one part of the script I call a text file that will have a list of user's names that can be deleted from, the contains of this file might change week to week.

```
#!/bin/bash
DAY=$(date +"%d%b%Y")
HOME='/home/user'
DOCS='/var/program/alpha/top/is'
SCRATCH='/var/program/beta/top/_temp/'
USER='/home/user/deleteuserdata.txt'
DELUSER=$USER
cd $SCRATCH 
rm -rf _temp-*/
cd $DOCS
while read DELUSER; do
find $DOCS/"$DELUSER"_info* -name "*.pdf" -size +1000k -exec rm {} \;
done < $USER > $HOME/"$DAY"dellogs.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should quote variables almost everywhere. Prefer pushd/popd over cd (easier to remember pervious path). Probably want to prefer `find -delete` over the spawn-some `-exec rm`. Add error checking (bash -e), and -x to see where it exits when it comes to that.

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

DELUSER="$USER" # setting this is useless because it's overriden in the while loop
pushd "$SCRATCH"
rm -Rf _temp-*/ || :
pushd "$DOCS"
while read DELUSER; do
    find "$DOCS/$DELUSER"_info* -name "*.pdf" -size +1000k -print -delete
done <"$USER" >"$HOME/${DAY}dellogs.txt"
popd
popd
```